# Consulta todas tabelas sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, mvc

Boa noite estou começando na carreira de desenvolvedor e estou criando uma aplicação que le um arquivo xml.

estou com dificuldade em passar um comando no banco de dados sql que me retorne todas as tabelas e seus atributos ( coluna e valores).

Obrigado

Comment: Qual a relação entre ler arquivo XML e obter a lista de tabelas e colunas?

Comment: no comando: `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns` deve haver todas as tabelas e colunas

Comment: a ideia é transformar uma consulta no banco sql server em um arquivo xml.

Estou usando o seguinte comando :

use AutomacaoTest
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
for xml path

a ideia era chegar proximo de algo :
<NomeTabela>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Descricao>Browser Google Chrome</Descricao>
  <Operacao>1</Operacao>
  <MassaDados>1</MassaDados>
</NomeTabela>
<NomeTabela>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Descricao>Browser Google Chrome</Descricao>
  <Operacao>1</Operacao>
  <MassaDados>1</MassaDados>
</NomeTabela>

Comment: não entendi uma coisa. vc quer gerar no sql um xml contendo todas as tabelas e seus valores?

Comment: isso , gerar um xml contendo todas as tabelas e os valores no sql , so q o SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns mostra apenas as colunas sem seus valores

Answer (score -1):

Boas, ve este exemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourStudentTable
FOR XML PATH('Student'), ROOT ('Students')
```

tirado de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654157/how-to-make-sql-query-result-to-xml-file